# LoopBack: How to Create an Extended User Model Relation

Tags: strongloop, loopback

I'm unable to create a relation from a model extended from the `User` model. For complete details - see [the issue I opened](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/3462). I created a `hasMany` / `belongsTo` relationship from a `User` extended model named `user` with a model named `account`.

common/models/user.json

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "plural": "users",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "accounts": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "account",
      "foreignKey": "userId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [{
    "accessType": "EXECUTE",
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$authenticated",
    "permission": "ALLOW",
    "property": "__create__accounts"
  }],
  "methods": {}
}
```

common/models/account.json

```
{
  "name": "account",
  "plural": "accounts",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "user": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "user",
      "foreignKey": "userId"
    }
  },
  "acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$authenticated",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "create"
    }
  ],
  "methods": {}
}
```

**The Issue**

In the Loopback API Explorer after creating a user, logging in, and setting the access token I attempt to create an user account entry via POST request (`/users/{id}/accounts` where `{id}` represents the user id). The response is a 404 with the following error message:

```
Shared class  \"User\" has no method handling POST /594fcbeee223ce23620a3e12/accounts?access_token=Dg8qkXIHEck9fS0taCPWxklSVwD6HivN7iVU0lq0SBhaXQ8dMJmo6j8WxQGBNKRD
```

I've followed documentation and tried a couple things, and even without ACL set at all - I'm seeing this issue. I created a [full example project here](https://github.com/adamhenson/loopback-api-example/tree/acl).

Has anyone run into this before? I'm guessing I need to add more ACL settings to my `user` model, but it's unclear to me what that would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide the base `User` model in `model-config.json`

```
{
  "User": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  ...
}
```

Since it's visible for remoting, it's still being used over your extended model. There is a small hint in a form of a warning, which could point you to this issue. You see it when the application is being bootstrapped.

*Warning: overriding remoting type user*

Comment: Thank you @IvanSchwarz. This was the answer. I would have never figured that out on my own. So I guess this only occurs when naming the `User` extended model `user`, because I found that when I named the model `appUser` - the issue did not exists. Anyways, thanks again! Full, corrected example [here](https://github.com/adamhenson/loopback-api-example/tree/example-relations-acl) - for anyone who stumbles upon this. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep. I assume case insensitive routing is to blame here.